# No funciona my OR en la condicion if de mi script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

tengo un script que mira la ultima linea del log, despues de formatearlo obtengo una palabra que me interesa del dicho log.

Si esa palabara es `nochg` o es `good` quiero que devuelva un `1` , de lo contario un `0`.

Mi script es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
resultNoIpUpdate=$(tail -n1 /var/log/noip.log | awk '{print $5}');
echo $resultNoIpUpdate;

if [ "$resultNoIpUpdate" = "nochg" ] ||  [ "$resultNoIpUdate" = "good" ];
then
  echo 1
else
  echo 0
fi
```

Pues bien, la palabra que me interesa esta almacenada en `resultNoIpUpdate` la cual contiene una palabra.

Pero estoy haciendo pruebas y cuando es `nochg` funciona bien, y queria probar con la segunda condicion (`good`) y es entonces cuando devuelve siempre 0. Para testear esta segunda parte estoy cambiado el fichero de los logs a mano, poniendo el ultimo al `good` manualmente.

Para debugearlo he puesto que retorne la var `resultNoIpUpdate` para saber que es lo que estoy esperando, y asi es. Esto es lo que obtengo:

```
[root]@{mi-servidor}:~/scripts# ./checkDNSUpdate.sh
 good
 0
```

Deberia de ser 1.

El fichero es algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si la captura del resultado es correcta, es posible que tengas un espacio en blanco delante de la palabra " good" y por eso no entre en el if?

Comment: He probado a hacerle un length y me sale n 4 characteres, asi que en principio no parece ser ese el problema :(

Comment: Pues te va a dar algo cuando te des cuenta que las variables que estas comparando no tienen el mismo nombre XD

Comment: Omg! Es verdad ! Ya funciona !!!! :O

Answer (score 0):

Cómo ya mencionaron probablemente un espacio sea el problema. Con el mismo awk puedes quitarlo usando `gsub` por ejemplo:

```
resultNoIpUpdate=$(tail -n1 /var/log/noip.log | awk '{gsub(/ /, "", $5); print $5}');
```

Explicación:

```
gsub(a,b,c)    match the regular expression a, replace it with b, 
               and do all this with the contents of c
```

Esp

```
gsub(a,b,c)    Encuentra la expresión regular a, la reemplaza con b, y actúa sobre los contenidos de c
```